# Authenticator, incorrect translate Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to convert a lot of code Java into Kotlin.

I found on stack how to set authentication with OkHttp:

```
 client.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (responseCount(response) >= 3) {
                return null; // If we've failed 3 times, give up. - in real life, never give up!!
            }
            String credential = Credentials.basic("name", "password");
            return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
        }
    });
```

It's look simple, but AndroidStudio translate this wrong, something like:

```
   client.authenticator(Authenticator { route, response ->
            if (responseCount(response) >= 3) {
                return@Authenticator null // If we've failed 3 times, give up. - in real life, never give up!!
            }
            val credential = Credentials.basic("name", "password")
            response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build()
        })
```

and I get error "too many arguments for public open fun Authenticator()"

What is wrong here ? How to fix it ? In my opinion, this should look different in Kotlin.

Answer (score 3):

Your Kotlin code should be like this:

```
client.authenticator(object:Authenticator {
  @Throws(IOException::class)
  fun authenticate(route:Route, response:Response):Request {
    if (responseCount(response) >= 3)
    {
      return null // If we've failed 3 times, give up. - in real life, never give up!!
    }
    val credential = Credentials.basic("name", "password")
    return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", 
credential).build()
  }
})
```

Comment: `@Throws` isn't necessary, and you should add `override` to `fun authenticate`.

Comment: i got underline by AndroidStudio this object:Authenticator with "too many  arguments for public open fun authenticator()"

Comment: 1. `authenticator` or `Authenticator`? 2. Try to go to the definition and see what AS thinks it's referring to.

Answer (score 1):

No, by itself this is a correct translation, you can see examples in [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) documentation. Judging from the error, you may have something else in scope also called `Authenticator`, so you should be more explicit and use an [anonymous object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) as in Randy Hall's answer.

Comment: i have anonymous class like in Randy asnwer and still have this error